# Every 7.5 minutes with cron

Tags: cron

How to handle fractions with cron? I want to schedule a task to run every 7.5 minutes, was not able to succeed with that.

Basically, 8 times in an hour.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `00:12`, `01:12`... and `00:05`, `01:05`... etc?

Comment: The best resolution you'll get with CRON is the nearest minute. Every 12 minutes would be possible with `0,12,24,36,48`.

Comment: I don't think cron can do fractional minutes. Would `00:12`, `00:30`, etc be acceptable? If not, you can delay every other time your script runs with `sleep(30)`

Comment: @Raptor  I think he is using European notation for decimal, so he means every 12 and a half minutes.

Comment: I changed my question to 7.5 -- 8 times in an hour @HoboSapiens

Comment: @Zettam So? You won't get 7.5minutes with CRON any more than you'll get 12.5 minutes.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen just changed the question a bit

Comment: @HoboSapiens I understand, I'm just trying my chances. 12.5 causes an overall delay, 7.5 is at least as simple as saying 8 times in an hour.

Comment: _'I'm just trying my chances.'_ - no, now you're just wasting our time.

Comment: The question is clear. You are not forced to answer it.

Comment: One possible solution would be to run a task every 7 minutes, then at the task level, sleep by a multiple of 30 seconds until it wraps to a 7 minute interval and start over.  I got here writing a "Slow watch widget" for my laptop with 7.5 minute ticks of the hour hand.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in cron directly. Cron doesn't support fractions in the time. You've got 2 options really:

1. Write your own wrapper which will run the task when needed.
2. Use an ugly hack in cron to schedule two tasks at the same time:

in your crontab:

```
*/25 * * * * the_task
*/25 * * * * sleep 750 ; the_task
```

This will spawn both tasks at the same time, but run the second one after sleeping 12.5 minutes. Just make sure your cron does start both tasks at the same time - I don't think the behaviour on 'every x minutes' is standardised.

Comment: How about every 7.5 minutes? it's still fractions but it's as simple to say "8 times in an hour" -- it does not delay like every 12.5 minutes question I asked initially.

Comment: The answer doesn't change, but the numbers do. You can figure out how.